# how to maintain sort order cost effectively in database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

This sort order of products for a particular supplier is stored in a table.

Eg:

```
ITEM_ID SORT_ORDER
100         1
101         2
105         3
106         4
108         5
```

and so on ...

Now, if supplier wants to display 1st product (100) at 5th position on his web page he can do it at his end,in order to display results as he desired we need to change sort values in the table as below.

The new sort order value of all the items gets updated and new table takes the form as following:

```
ITEM_ID SORT_ORDER
100         5
101         1
105         2
106         3
108         4
```

and so on ...

It is observed that for changing sort order of 1 product, we have to updtae all the rows of this table for that particular supplier.
This is a costly exercise.

We are looking for a solution to this problem which maintains the sort order of products of that supplier with the most optimized & cost effective method.

any alternate solution to maintain sort order in any other way than this

Comment: "costly exercise" to update a few rows? how many items does your typical supplier have?

Comment: @ JeffreyKemp around 1 lack in worst case and average case 1000+

Comment: lack?  anyway, if your average is 1000 that's quite small.

Comment: the main problem comes when 1 lack suppliers did small change in their ordering(assuming each supplier with 1000 products) then we need to update 1 lack* 1000 which is very bad.

Comment: 1 lakh = 0.1 million 
source=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Names_of_numbers_in_English :)

Comment: @ Jeffrey Kemp yha its mention in this page too :-) peace

100,000 one hundred thousand or one lakh (Indian English)

Answer (score 2):

> It is observed that for changing sort order of 1 product, we have to updtae all the rows of this table for that particular supplier. This is a costly exercise.

Well, yes you need to update all the rows, however, it could be done in just two steps. In plain SQL using **two UPDATE statements**.

**Test Case:**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t
  2      (ITEM_ID int, SORT_ORDER int);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT ALL
  2      INTO t (ITEM_ID, SORT_ORDER)
  3           VALUES (100, 1)
  4      INTO t (ITEM_ID, SORT_ORDER)
  5           VALUES (101, 2)
  6      INTO t (ITEM_ID, SORT_ORDER)
  7           VALUES (105, 3)
  8      INTO t (ITEM_ID, SORT_ORDER)
  9           VALUES (106, 4)
 10      INTO t (ITEM_ID, SORT_ORDER)
 11           VALUES (108, 5)
 12  SELECT * FROM dual;

5 rows created.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

Now, **first update** is for the **`ITEM_ID 100`** to set it to **`SORT_ORDER 5`**:

```
SQL> UPDATE t SET sort_order = 5 WHERE item_id = 100;

1 row updated.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

   ITEM_ID SORT_ORDER
---------- ----------
       100          5
       101          2
       105          3
       106          4
       108          5

SQL>
```

Now, **second update** is for all the **`other ITEM_IDs`** to set it to **`SORT_ORDER -1`**:

```
SQL> UPDATE t SET sort_order = sort_order - 1
  2  WHERE item_id <> 100;

4 rows updated.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

   ITEM_ID SORT_ORDER
---------- ----------
       100          5
       101          1
       105          2
       106          3
       108          4

SQL>
```

So, the task is achieved with just two update statements.

**Update** Based on Jeffrey's comment below, it could be done in a single update statement using a **CASE** statement.

For example,

```
UPDATE t
SET    sort_order = CASE item_id
                      WHEN 100 THEN 5
                      ELSE sort_order - 1
                    END;
```

If there is any **unique constraint** on the `sort_order` column, then this approach is better as compared to my previous demonstration with two update statements.

Comment: It'd be even simpler with just one update statement, e.g.: `update t set sort_order = case item_id when 100 then 5 else sort_order - 1 end` - also, this will avoid violating a unique constraint on the table if it exists.

Comment: but the problem is it din't solve the problem i.e. number rows updated per table

Answer (score 1):

better solution will be giving a values with a long difference between them and then we need to update only one value
eg.

`ID     SORT_ORDER
 100      500
 102      1000
 103      1500
 104      2000`

if we change order we need to update only one row

`ID     SORT_ORDER
 104      250 
 100      500
 102      1000
 103      1500`

but we need to keep track the number of valid operation can perform and need to reset data if no more possibilities are found.

Comment: Might be a good idea to allow floating-point numbers in the sort order column, that way you can continue dividing by two until you run out of precision.

Answer (score 0):

*It is observed that for changing sort order of 1 product, we have to update all the rows of this table for that particular supplier. This is a costly exercise.*

You can sort all item in front end process and arrange all comma separated `ITEM_ID` in sorted order and save it in database (using `Primary Key`) in a single `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: better solution will be giving a values with a long difference between them and then we need to update only one value
eg.
`ID     SORT_ORDER
 100      500
 102      1000
 103       1500
104        2000
`
if we change order we need to update only one row

`ID     SORT_ORDER
104      250 
100      500
 102      1000
 103       1500
`